# Why do files and dirs placed in httpd document root have group changed to _www?

Tags: finder, permission, apache, ftp

This is a bit technical:

I do localhost development on Mac High Sierra and other
Mac systems on my local network.

I have been working on content management code in php.
Recently I have come up with the idea of adding my FTP
user account to the _www group.

Then files placed in the document root folder can be turned
over to the web server user account by copying the FTP user
owned content using a php script. So this does not change the
group. That is also done by php script I am developing.

The point is to be able to edit content both with php and with
FTP user and set "everyone" to no access. Directories are given
0770 perms and files 0660 perms.

BUT I have a directory on the desktop with FTP user ownership
and "staff" group ownership. When I upload this content to the
document root using FTP client the content group is changed
to _www (but not the content ownership). The php script is
not a CLI script that would be run by the FTP client (Fetch).

I have tried using the finder to place this content in document
root. Doing that the group is NOT changed.

But, since the content has been moved to the document root folder,
I want to copy it back to the desktop. The copy now on the desktop
has _www as group.

THE QUESTION:

Is there some behind the scenes security issue with this approach?
Luckily I can use SUDO (or root) to change ownership and group 
assignments.

More info:

But on a remote site that will not be possible and I am having
trouble with the scripts not executing chgrp (change group) and
NO errors are reported. The code just doesn't do it.

I have been doing development long enough to know to test to see
that the code is actually being attempted by the script as it runs.

Thank you for time and attention

JK

(EDIT) further info;
I am making headway on php script dev.
The _www group issue is not turning out
to be as much of a problem as I thought.
I have to write a recursive function to
to the copying and deleting the original
and then renaming the copy to the original.
I have written a recursive method that does
do this but it is embedded in another class
def and is private and only usable in the
context for which it was developed.

Comment: On macOS, the default is for newly created files to inherit their group assignment from the directory they're created in. This can be overridden (to some extent) by the program doing the creating, but that's the default. Moving a file does not change either the owner or group.

Comment: OK; so the FTP client copies content to the document root. So the content copied to document root inherits the group of localhost document root (set to _www). And copying the content in document root with the  finder sets the copy content group to _www as well (?)